# Eloquent Query: All News with same categories. Pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, relationship

I need to get all the news that has the same (one or more) categories as a specific new in an Eloquent query. And I dont know with pivot table.

I have 3 tables:

**News**

```
id | title | content
```

**NewsxCategory**   (Pivot Table)

```
news_id | category_id
```

**NewsCategory**

```
id | name
```

**Eloquent Models**

```
// NewsCategory model
class NewsCategory extends Model
{

}

// News Model
class News extends Model
{

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(NewsCategory::class, 'news_x_category', 'news_id', 'category_id');
    }

}
```

I tried this.

In helper:

```
/**
 *  only related news
 *
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public static function relatedNews(News $new)
{
    $categories = $new->categories(); //obtain all categories of $new

    return News::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($categories) {
        $query->whereIn('new_id', $categories);
    });
}
```

And in view:

```
<div class="related-articles">
    <h5>{{ __('RELATED ARTICLES') }}</h5>
    <ul class="articles">
       @foreach ( App\Helpers\News::relatedNews($newsItem) as $new)
            <li>
                <h6>{{ $new->title }}</h6>
                <p>{{ $new->publication_date }}</p>
            </li>
       @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

But helper always return `null`.

Also I tried in helper:

```
return News::with('categories')->where('category_id',$categories )->get();
```

But this option return all news.

I need all news related, I mean news with similar categories. Pivot tables give me a headache.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `whereIn` clause, you need to pass array of ids. But you are not passing correct.

So here is the correct one.

```
/**
 *  only related news
 *
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public static function relatedNews(News $new)
{
    $categoryIds = $new->categories->pluck('category_id')->toArray(); //obtain all categories of $new

    return News::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($categoryIds) {
        $query->whereIn('category_id', $categoryIds);
    });
}
```

I think after change above function changes. you will get related news.

**Updated**

If you want to print related news then use this:

```
@foreach ( App\Helpers\News::relatedNews($newsItem)->get() as $new)
    {{ $new->title }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for you help but helper still return 0 news. I also tried: $categoryIds = $newsItem->categories()->pluck('category_id') and with this I obtain a collection with categoríes of this new. But result is the same...

Comment: Can you try this ` $categoryIds = $new->categories->pluck('category_id')->toArray();`?

Comment: This way If  I  use App\Helpers\News::relatedNews($newsItem)->count()   obtain 3. That is correct. But when I try to access:  @foreach ( App\Helpers\News::relatedNews($newsItem) as $new){ $new->title   } I dont aobtain nothing. Why?